# Different QWidget behaviour on Windows and Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qwidget

QWidget is created after some time in my app. I start my app. Then I use internet browser. On Linux my new widget appeares over my browser, but on Windows - not. Widget has parent widget. How to fix it on Linux?

both parent and my widget have only `setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);` The Linux OS is Xubuntu. And one difference in parent class:

```
#if defined(Q_WS_X11) 
   setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint); 
#else 
   setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint); 
#endif
```

Comment: You should state which Lunix version you are using, and maybe add screenshots and the initialization code of your widget.

Comment: parent is QWidget too. both parent and my widget have only     setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus); The Linux OS is Xubuntu. And one difference in parent class:  #if defined(Q_WS_X11)
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
#else
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
#endif

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows prevents other programs from stealing the focus while some other OS may not enforce that.

When you create your widget, you should set the [window state](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#WindowState-enum) before making it visible.
For instance

```
 QWidget* lateWidget = new QWidget(this); // or add to layout or whatever
 lateWidget->setWindowState(this->windowState());
 lateWidget->show();
```

**Edit:**

[From the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#visible-prop) :

> A widget that happens to be obscured by other windows on the screen is
>   considered to be visible

Which means that if you open the browser on top of `parent` then `lateWidget->show()` will ask to the window system to be activated.`lateWidget` which then pop on top and gain user mouse and keyboard focus.

before showing `lateWidget` a quick fix is to use

```
 lateWidget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
```

Comment: Does this make sense? What he wants is simply `lateWidget->setWindowState(Qt::WindowActive)`

Comment: I want widget to not appears on top on both windows and linux. I realise that they have the same behaviour